# The window does not appear on top of all Windows when you click the keyboard shortcut again

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside

The window does not appear on top of all Windows when you click the keyboard shortcut again
but with the first two clicks, the window becomes on top of the Windows and can disappear. no problem.

also, the code starts working normally if I clicked on the window. before losing focus.

setFocus(Qt::ActiveWindowFocusReason)method
doesn't work

```
self.hide()
    print(str(self.top))
    if(self.top==False):
           self.setWindowFlags(QtCore. Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.show()
        self.activateWindow()   


        self.top=True
    else:
             self.setWindowFlags(QtCore. Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint|QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
         self.top=False
         self.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "click the keyboard shortcut"? Are you using a keyboard shortcut or the mouse click? Also, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I use it, keyboard shortcut, sorry there are problems with English, I'm just from Russia.

Comment: I can understand you might have language difficulties, but the code you provided is unusable as it is, and we really can't help you with that. Provide us an MRE as explained in the link I gave you in the previous comment, and ensure that we are actually able to reproduce it just by copying, pasting and run it. Read more about [formatting your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) too so that you can understand how to do it properly.